# Override fill colour not changing top-level symbol

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, symbology, legend, color

I have a shapefile with the maps of the world in different historical periods ([`CShapes 2.0`](https://icr.ethz.ch/data/cshapes/)) and I need to map each country colour to a list to ensure consistency. On QGIS, I created a table with the country names and related hexcodes and joined to the shapefile, so each country has now a `country_color` field associated to it.

I then go on setting up the "Symbol" in Layer properties/Symbology (1), select the Simple fill layer (2), and assign the fill colour to the value in `country_colour` (3 and 4).

[image]

This works as intended insofar as it does change the colour of each country on the map. However, the legend does not change accordingly as the top-level symbol remains unchanged.

I do not seem to find any option to assign an expression to the top-level symbol colour, but I am sure there must be a way, either via GUI or PyQGIS script - yet, I seem to be hopeless at finding that way.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately it looks like there is no way to update the legend using QGIS without any python script. Using python you can iterate over all features and create a categorized symbology (a lot of the code was copied from [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/318474/setting-style-for-categorized-vector-in-pyqgis)). The data used here are the countries when typing `world` into the coordinate field in QGIS ([easter egg](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/407331/where-to-find-all-hidden-layers-effects-in-qgis)). A column `color` was added which holds the hex-code of the colors - only three colors have been used.

```py
# Access Data Layer and create Data Provider
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('data')[0]

# Get indizes
fidIdx = layer.fields().names().index("fid")
colorIdx = layer.fields().names().index("color")
nameIdx = layer.fields().names().index("NAME")

# Create list to store symbology properties
categories = []

def xstr(s):
    if s is None:
        return ''
    return str(s)

# Iterate features of layer
for feature in layer.getFeatures():
    
    # Get fid attribute
    fid = feature.attributes()[fidIdx]
    
    # Get color attribute
    color = feature.attributes()[colorIdx]
    
    # Get name attribute
    name = feature.attributes()[nameIdx]
    
    # Convert name to string if it might be None
    name = xstr(name)

    # Automatically set symbols based on layer's geometry
    symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(layer.geometryType())
    
    # Set colour
    symbol.setColor(QColor(color))

        
    # Set the renderer properties
    category = QgsRendererCategory(fid, symbol, name)
    categories.append(category)
    
    
# Field name
expression = 'fid'

# Set the categorized renderer
renderer = QgsCategorizedSymbolRenderer(expression, categories)
layer.setRenderer(renderer)

# Refresh layer
layer.triggerRepaint()
```

[image]